# syntax region: start with a group

Tags: vim

That's for assembly coding:
I'd like to highlight lines that start with one-operand-menemonic but contain a comma.

I tried something like this:

```
sy keyword ONE_OP_MNEM jal jr " <--- this are mnemonics expecting 1 operand
sy match COMMA /,/ " <--- group to be used in next line
sy region ERROR start=one_op_mnemonic end=/[;$]/ contains=comma
```

vim complains about `start=ONE_OP_MNEM`.
Can someone correct my syntax or suggest another way how to highlight operand mismatch of this kind?

Comment: can you be more specific about the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to include comments on the same line where you define the keyword