# Can vim syntax group be used as a start parameter in syntax match?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Suppose I have defined a bunch of `syntax keyword` and `syntax match` for some syntax group called `Foo`.

I would now like to define a `syntax region` which begins with any match on the syntax group `Foo` and ends with a literal tab. It would look something like this.

```
syntax region Bar start=Foo end='\t'
```

**Is this possible?**

I have looked at `:help :syn-pattern` and `:help :syn-region`, but none of them address this question. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153078/syntax-region-start-with-a-group) is kind of similar, but it did not receive good answers (possibly due to lack of sufficient clarity) and is two years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the start and end patterns of a `:syn region` must be a pattern; you cannot reference another syntax group. However, with use of `matchgroup=`, you may be able to avoid defining a separate syntax keyword / match for the start pattern. To avoid that the matchgroup highlighting also applies to the end pattern, just switch the argument order, like this:

```
:syntax region Bar end='\t' matchgroup=Foo start='foo'
```

Comment: If I am literally trying to start with only elements of that group, what is the correct argument to pass to `start`?

Comment: For keywords, you need to build a regexp that matches any: `start="\<\%(keyword1\|keyword2\|keyword3\)\>"`.

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing exactly that because it would be a very long and ugly regex encoding information already known to vim through the syntax group. I thought your answer implied that avoidance was possible with some magic value of start together with matchgroup.

Comment: Unfortunately, `matchgroup` just instructs Vim to use different highlighting for the start / end, **not** to reference another group. So, you have to have that long ugly regexp, but you don't need to duplicate this just to get them highlighted different that the region itself.